# Why does my <ul> have a background of an element which isn't its parent?

Tags: css, background-color

I am trying to build a page with a header, which includes a navigation bar at the bottom. However, the navigation bar has the background colour of the main content, not of the header.

I searched the site for similar problems, and tried overflow: hidden, or adding overflow: auto to .main, as suggested, but none of these solutions worked. I have also tried removing some lines from my css, such as float: left; which also didn't work. Adding background: inherit to ul only gives the background colour to a small area around the nav bar, not the width of the header.

```css
.main {
  background-color: DarkOliveGreen;
  border-radius: 15px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  height: 800px;
}
header {
  background: Chartreuse;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
ul {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -45px;
}
li {
  display: inline;
  background: cyan;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  margin-left: -5px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 35px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
img {
  max-height: 150px;
  max-width: 150px;
}
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 60px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <header>
    <h1>Gallery</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/gallery.html">Gallery</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <div class="pictures">
    <article class="item">
      <img src="#">
      <h2>Image 1</h2>
    </article>
    <!-- several more .item articles with an image and h2. -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `header { overflow:hidden }`. When you float something inside a container that container will collapse (unless it contains something that is not floated). Setting its overflow to hidden forces the box to expand with the floated element. Edit: Oh, and the positioning is also problematic. Because the element is absolutely positioned the container does not know how high it should be (so it becomes 0px high).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to `position: absolute` and `float: left` which makes the element to go out of the document flow.

```css
.main {
  background-color: DarkOliveGreen;
  border-radius: 15px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  height: 800px;
}
header {
  background: Chartreuse;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0 0;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
ul {
  display: block;
  margin-left: -45px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
li {
  display: inline;
  background: cyan;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  margin-left: -5px;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 35px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
img {
  max-height: 150px;
  max-width: 150px;
}
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 60px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  float: left;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <header>
    <h1>Gallery</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/index.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="/gallery.html">Gallery</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </header>
  <div class="pictures">
    <article class="item">
      <img src="#">
      <h2>Image 1</h2>
    </article>
    <!-- several more .item articles with an image and h2. -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS file in header change
background: Chartreuse; 
to
background-color: Chartreuse;